# Unable to connect to mysql on remote server

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh, centos

I want to connect a mysql database on remote server(simulating by virtual machine) by c# :

remote server OS: Centos 8

Remote server IP:192.168.1.34

Port:22

database name: dbname

database Port=3306

I've made a connection to remote server through SSH method successfully.but I cant access to server and database directly.
note: I've installed apache server and phpmyadmin on remote server and I can connect successfully via webpage by http://192.168.1.34/phpmyadmin

connection string :server=192.168.1.34;Database=dbname;port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=dbpass;CharSet=utf8;

error message: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

[Error Message picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGziO.png)

Comment: A `192.168.1.xxx` IP is NOT a remote server IP.  That's a private internal IP address.

Comment: The root account is normally configured to only allow connections from the local machine (127.0.0.1). now is your chance to do things properly, setup a new account and allow it to be used from your IP Address

Comment: I checked it. I changed host from localhost but problem did not solve.